# Tag icon missing in questions list

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I keep the main SO 'interesting' questions list open most of the day and refresh it often.  The problem is half of the time, the android tag icon is missing for every question, but still works on the right column under 'favorite' tags (see screenshot below).

A temporary fix is just to refresh the page, and that usually fixes it until the next refresh.  Is there an easy permanent fix I'm missing?

I've tried clearing browsing data (browsing history, download history, cache) and close & reopen Chrome often, but this continues to happen.

Edit: It typically doesn't happen if I chain refresh the page.  It happens after it's been sitting for 15-20 mins, or more, and I return to update the list.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce this here. What browser version are you using?

Comment: Chrome: Version 25.0.1364.172 m - I'll edit the question, but it typically doesn't happen if I chain refresh the page.  It happens after it's been sitting for 15-20 mins, or more, and I return to update the list.

Comment: Can you inspect the element with the chrome dev tools when it's happening? I can't repro, but in the source those two spots use the exact same image URL when it's working.

Comment: They're the same img src, even when it's broken - <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short: A chrome extension called Redirector was the culprit. Thanks to Wooble for a hint he didn't even mean to give me for figuring this out!

Extra Info:
Ironically, I used two ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097781/chrome-downloads-png-image-links-i-want-them-to-open-for-viewing-in-a-new-tab) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323946/how-can-i-edit-chrome-mime-type-mappings/12235918#12235918)) SO articles a few weeks back to try to figure out how to force chrome to show all .png files rather than automatically downloading some of them.  The tips didn't fix my particular need, so I just disabled the whole extension.  I assume the individual png rules could be tweaked to not interfere like they were, but I won't be researching that for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this, seems fine at my end.  If it working after refreshing it is certainly not a bug.  Try a different browser to see if the issue persists.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try in IE8 today and see what happens.